# Scraping website for book listings, checking if database contains relevant listings, and displaying result in a Django view

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, django

This code works but is very slow.  I am scraping a website for urls for various books, and then checking to see if we have complete records of those books in our database.  After I process the URL to get the book info, I see if we have it in our database.  If we don't, I move on, that's fine.  If we do, I need to check that we have a matching BookTextVer type; that foreign keys to the book, and filters on an attribute from the URL.  If we have it, great; if not, I add it to my list of dictionaries to eventually pass to the django template.

```
def book_missing(request):
    data = []
    books = book.objects.all()
    sitemap = "www.sitemap.com"
    page = requests.get(sitemap)
    tree = objectify.fromstring(page.content)
    regex = re.compile("books-(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)")
    for node in tree.getchildren():
        book_url = node.book.text
        # e.g. https://www.sitemap.com/fdsys/pkg/books-27hr200nf/content-detail.html
        m = regex.search(book_url)
        object_type_cd = m.groups()[1]  # hr
        book_num = m.groups()[2]  # 200
        book_type = m.groups()[3]  # nf
        try:
            book = books.get(book_num=book_num,
                             object_type_cd_id=object_type_cd.upper())
        except book.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        if (BookTextVer.objects.filter(
            book=book,
            book_text_ver_type__short_name=book_type.upper()).exists()):
            pass  # matching book type exists, no processing needed
        else:
            data.append({"book": object_type_cd.upper() + book_num,
                         "book_type": book_type.upper()})
    context = {
        'data': data,
    }
    return render(request, 'etl/reports/gpo-book-missing.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

> After I process the URL to get the book info, I see if we have it in our database. If we don't, I move on, that's fine.

I guess you're referring to this part of the code:

> ```
> try:
>     book = books.get(book_num=book_num,
>                      object_type_cd_id=object_type_cd.upper())
> except book.DoesNotExist:
>     pass
> ```

This doesn't do what you described,
because after the `pass`,
the rest of the loop body is executed instead of moving on the next iteration.
Perhaps you meant to use `continue` there instead of `pass`.

---

Instead of having an empty `if` block and an `else` block here,
it would be better to flip the condition and have only an `if` block without an `else`:

> ```
> if (BookTextVer.objects.filter(
>     book=book,
>     book_text_ver_type__short_name=book_type.upper()).exists()):
>     pass  # matching book type exists, no processing needed
> else:
>     data.append({"book": object_type_cd.upper() + book_num,
>                  "book_type": book_type.upper()})
> ```

---

The query on `BookTextVer` tries to match by `short_name`.
Is that field indexed in the database.
If not, the query will be inevitably slow,
and indexing should be a significant improvement.

---

The current implementation runs 1 or 2 queries for every `node in tree.getchildren()`.
You might get better performance if you first collect all the `book_num`, `book_type`, `object_type_cd` values from the document,
and formulate a single database query or constant number of database queries.
That would be a major change,
and possibly you might need to forego Django's OR-mapping benefits,
but the reduced number of database queries could make a big difference.

Comment: You're right on the pass vs continue... I don't know why that didn't trigger an error since I use that (non-existent) book in the next part of the query